# iOS 8 Mobile Safari Images Loading Corrupt

Tags: ios, html, safari, ios8, mobile-safari

Having a very difficult time tracking down a solution to this bug, hoping someone can help me.

My web app http://www.customozer.com loads fine on desktop, but on mobile safari, some images load corrupt (screenshots below in comments).

This issue does not appear when I use chrome on my ipad (iOS 8.1.2), just safari and saved web apps.

What's also interesting is that when loaded directly from my local MAMP stack using an ngrok tunnel (http://alexgoodwinmedia.ngrok.com/Oz-Snowboards/site/app.php), the issue does not appear. Files on my local machine and on the customozer.com server are synced.

From what I've read, there's a mobile safari issue with loading large amounts of AJAX data.. but that's not how these images are being loaded.

Does anyone have some insight into how can this issue be resolved? Happy to provide more details/tests.

Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/WQBaP6L.jpg (sorry, reputation limited the number of links I could post)

Comment: Another Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/9NM17f7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rather extensive testing, I've finally concluded that the PNG images were being corrupt by an old version of PNGlib (a GDlib element). By moving my project to a new server that allowed for a newer version of GDlib to be installed, I was able to fix the problem.